# $.ajax(...) POST to Jersey WebService, unable to get back HTTP error details (status code, etc)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, http-status-code-404

Here's my setup:

Java REST web service (implemented with Jersey). I use JQuery to to HTTP GETs and POSTs towards it.

My JQuery AJAX config is as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("=== error function ===");
            console.log("jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status);
            console.log("jqXHR.responseText=" + jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log("textStatus=" + textStatus);
            console.log("errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
        }
    });

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, settings, exception ) {
    console.log("=== ajaxError function ===");
    console.log("settings.url=" + settings.url);
    console.log("jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status);
    console.log("jqXHR.responseText=" + jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log("exception=" + exception);
});
```

**If I do a HTTP GET to an invalid URL:**

```
$.getJSON("http://validServer/invalidAddress", 
        requestJSON, 
        function(responseJSON) {
            //...
        });
```

I get nice error details from both the "error" and "ajaxError" configurations:

```
=== error function ===
jqXHR.status=404
jqXHR.responseText=[web server 404 message]
textStatus=error
errorThrown=Not Found
=== ajaxError function ===
settings.url=http://validServer/invalidAddress
jqXHR.status=404
jqXHR.responseText=[web server 404 message]
exception=Not Found
```

Also, if I look in Chrome's Network inspector Tab I can see than an (unsuccesfull) HTTP GET was performed.

**If I do a HTTP POST to an invalid URL:**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://validServer/invalidAddress",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(requestJSON),
      dataType: "text",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      success: function(responseJSON){
          //...
      }
});
```

<strike>First, it's pretty weird that when I look in Chrome's console, I can see that in fact an (unsuccesfull) HTTP OPTIONS was performed. I've noticed that even with valid JQuery ajax HTTP POSTs, Chrome's console reports that first an HTTP OPTIONS was made and *then* the HTTP POST.</strike>. This behavior is normal, as I am usign [cross-site requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

However, my main issue is that now, the output of the above error-handling code gives almost no details on the error:

```
=== error function ===
jqXHR.status=0
jqXHR.responseText=
textStatus=error
errorThrown=
=== ajaxError function ===
settings.url=http://validServer/invalidAddress
jqXHR.status=0
jqXHR.responseText=
exception=
```

**My question is:**

How do I get from JQuery's Ajax POST the details of an error (HTTP Status Code, Message, etc), like I do when I do an Ajax GET ?

**Update**

I should mention that the option of passing the error function immediately when I make the Ajax POST has the same issue. If I do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://validServer/invalidAddress",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(requestJSON),
      dataType: "text",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      success: function(responseJSON){
          //...
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
});
```

The console output for the above code is the same as in my first example, no HTTP Status Code, no server error message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> **My question is:**
>        How do I get from JQuery's Ajax POST the details of an error  (HTTP Status Code, Message, etc), like I do when I do an Ajax GET ?

Try this pattern (utilizing `$.getJSON()`, `$.post()`, `beforeSend`, `statusCode`, `jqxhr` object)

```
$(function () {
    var urls = ["/echo/jsons/", "/echo/json/"];

    var callback = function (j, s, e, name) {
        if (j.status === (403 || 404) && s === "error") {
      console.log(j.state()
                  , name
                  , j.status
                  , s
                  , e
                  , "\n\n");
      alert(j._url
            + "\n" + j.status 
            + "\n" 
            + s 
            + "\n" 
            + JSON.stringify(j, s, e));

        request(false, urls[1]);
        };
    };

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) {
            jqxhr._url = settings.url;
            settings.headers = {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json"
            };
            jqxhr._headers = settings.headers;   
        },
        statusCode : { 
            // `success` callback
            200 : function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            alert(jqxhr._url 
                  + "\n" + jqxhr.status 
                  + "\n" + textStatus 
                  + "\n" + data.abc);

            },
            // `error` callback
            403 : function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            callback(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown, String(jqxhr.status + ' "callback"'));           
            },
            404 : function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            callback(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown, String(jqxhr.status + ' "callback"'));           
            }
        }
    });
    var request = 
        function(_getJSON, url) {
            var _request = (_getJSON === true ? $.getJSON(url) : $.post(url, {
        json: JSON.stringify({"abc":123})
        }, "text")
        );
            _request.then(
          // `success` callback
          function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            if (textStatus === "success" && jqxhr.responseJSON) {
                console.log(jqxhr.state()
                            , jqxhr._url
                            , jqxhr.status
                            , textStatus
                            , jqxhr._headers
                            , JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
                            , data.abc
                            , jqxhr               
                            , "\n");

            };
          }
        // `error` callback
        , function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqxhr.state()
                    , jqxhr._url
                    , jqxhr.status
                    , textStatus
                    , errorThrown
                    , jqxhr._headers
                    , jqxhr
                    , "\n\n");
        return jqxhr.promise().state();  
        });

            return _request.promise().state()
        };
    $.when(request(true, urls[0]), request(false, urls[0]))
    .always(function(a, b) {
      console.log(a, b, "\n")
    }); 
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/yC6Uu/

Comment: Thank you for the effort. This didn't solve my problem completly, but it got me on a good path.

Answer (score 0):

Just add error callback in ajax request and handle the response

```
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://validServer/invalidAddress",
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(requestJSON),
          dataType: "text",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
          },
          success: function(responseJSON){
              //...
          },
          error: function(reserr){
            console.log(reserr);
          }
    });
```

`reserr` comes in JSON format, there you can obtain http error code printing `reserr.status` to console.
You can refer to [JQuery Ajax API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On your java action/script add this to the response:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

This will allow you to post from another domain. Basically because you are posting from another domain the server side block you before even throwing an error.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already done this. I really think the issue is at the JQuery level, not at the server or HTTP levels: if I inspect the HTTP traffic (via Chrome's Network Console, for example), I can see that when issuing a POST to an invalid URL from JQuery, an HTTP OPTIONS is first made, the server returns HTTP Status 404 and error message in the HTTP response, but then I can't "get" to these in JQuery (the jqXHR object has empty HTTP status, the error object contains only the string "error", etc).

Comment: If the first request is an `OPTIONS` request, you are dealing with `CORS`. The `OPTIONS` request is called a `preflight request`. Check your network tab and make sure you are using a valid endpoint. If you receive a 404 it will never work because the endpoint is not found. Copy the link from the network tab into your addressbar and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should make jsonp request in place of json request. and allow crossDomain true